# Unable to find SASL server implementation?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

**There's No issue with java version**

**The mapper phase has begun if there were issue related to version it would have thrown earlier**

[Its throwing some SASL Exception ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq2Z3.png)

Here are the errors.
Mapper face has already begun but it's not able to proceed further due to SASL?

**2018-06-17 11:15:54,420 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2018-06-17 11:15:54,440 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1529225370089_0093 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1529225370089_0093 failed 2 times due to Error launching appattempt_1529225370089_0093_000002. Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Unable to find SASL server implementation for DIGEST-MD5**